# use of minimum values with array's in simple problems

Tags: java, arrays, range, max, minimum

I'm learning Java and as part of my work requires that I be able to do things like calculate the range of values in an array (max - min + 1). I'm not allowed to use methods like collections.min(array). So far my solution is like this:

```
public static int range(int[] data){
int min = 99999999;
int max = 0; 
int test = 0;
int range = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     test = data[i];

     if (test > max)
         max = test;
     if (test < min) 
         min = test;
}
range = (max - min) + 1;
return range;
```

}

While it works for them it isn't particularly elegant. Having a minimum value of  9999999 works but if I end up having a problem using numbers larger than that, it doesn't work.

I feel like there should be a better solution but I'm not seeing a way to find the minimum value without setting my int min to a very high value. Otherwise the array may have very large numbers and the minimum would never change since the value's in the array are always greater than it.

Comment: consider using Integer.MIN_VALUE && MAX_VALUE

Comment: Also no need to store `range` just return `(max - min) + 1`

Comment: There's predefined value in Java called Integer.MAX_VALUE and it equals to 2^31 - 1 which is the maximum value for an int number.

Comment: Using `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` is one alternative.  Another is to set `max` and `min` to the value of the first element and start your loop at 1.  (This won't work on an empty array, but an empty array poses special problems anyway because you have to make a decision about how the `max` and `min` should be defined, or whether they should be defined.)

Comment: MAX_VALUE works thank you but does that require any special imports or does it being "predefined" mean its always accessible

Comment: Also than you ajb that answer is probably what I was thinking of!

Comment: `Integer` is in the `java.lang` package, which means it's always accessible (and therefore `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is always accessible).

Comment: @ScaryWombat You forgot the semicolon at the end of your sentence :P

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for pointing that out.  BTW you forgot `//` at the beginning of your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method returns the range for all non-null arrays of at least one element, otherwise it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. This is accomplished by the sanity check of `max >= min` which is only `true` if our original initialized values for `min` and `max`are unchanged. That can only happen if the `for` loop is skipped, which only happens for a null or empty array. If the array contains any valid `int`, even `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, this sanity check succeeds.

```
public static int range(int[] list){

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int i = 0; list != null && i < list.length; i++){
        int current = list[i];

        if(current > max){
             max = current;
        }

        if(current < min){
             min = current;
        }
    }

    if(max >= min){
        return max-min+1;
    }
    else throw IllegalArgumentException("Zero-length and null arrays have an undefined range!");
}
```